# How to restart specific structured streaming queries with a Databricks workflow job

Tags: databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I have a notebook that is hosting near 100 streaming queries, 2 of them die occasionally.
However, restarting the whole job may take 4 hours. Is it possible to restore the failed streaming queries without restarting the whole job?